# How do I print lines separately from a txt file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script that needs to print line 1 from a txt file, take a 3 second break, print line 2, take a 3 second break and continue until the whole text file is printed this way. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to show your attempt at solving this yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
file = open("abc.txt","r") #<-- Opening file as read mode
data = file.read()         #<-- Reading data
file.close()               #<-- Closing file
data = data.split("\n")    #<-- Splitting by new lines
for i in data:             #<-- Looping through splitted data
    print(i)               #<-- Printing line
    time.sleep(3)          #<-- Waiting for 3 seconds
```

Comment: (a) Please don't answer questions that are blatantly off-topic. (b) Please don't write code for people; Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service and you're setting a precedent. (c) When you answer, please provide an explanation of how your solution solves the problem. A code dump on its own isn't very helpful for learning. (This isn't easy to do for this question, which is a good indicator that it's off-topic as too broad.)